# How to remove all strings except the given value

Tags: java, regex, string

So my code is:

```
String value = "123456"
```

I want to remove everything except for `2` and `5`. the output will be `25` the program should work even the value is changed for example:

```
String value = "463312"
```

The output will be `2`.

I tried `replaceAll()` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share your code with `replaceAll` ?

Comment: Find a regex that expresses everything but 2 and 5. That shouldn't be too hard to come up with yourself.

Answer (score 5):

It does, just you have to use the right regular expression.

```
String newValue = value.replaceAll("[^25]", "");
```

This one says that everything that doesn't (`^` stands for the negation) match the items between `[` and `]` (set of values) will be erased.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex **[^25]**

```
String newStr = value.replaceAll("[^25]","");
```